# Alternative to servicewrapper for java?

Tags: java, windows-services, service

I've used [ServiceWrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp) a few times in the past, however, the dual license is somewhat complex for commercial products (generally you have to pay them).  Are there are fully FOSS alternatives with similar functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) seems to be the best alternative, though I have not yet completed my evaluation.

Comment: Did you complete your evaluation? I've installed it, and works right till now, do you have any new opinion up to date? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try [Apache Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html).  It's what Tomcat uses on Windows.  There is also [Apache jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html) for Unix; they are both part of a parent project called [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Which functionality do you need exactly?

In their table I didn't see anything non-trivial. But it would help if you narrow down your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

We use the open source [JavaService](http://javaservice.ow2.org/index.html) package.

Edit: We use an older version of this package (when it was being maintained by the original developer, Alexandria Software Consulting).  I have not had a chance to look at the improvements made since then.