# Self restart program on segfault under Linux

Tags: c, linux, restart, segmentation-fault, recover

Under Linux what would be the best way for a program to restart itself on a crash by catching the exception in a crashhandler (for example on a segfault)?

Comment: Check some answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545993/restoring-restarting-a-java-daemon-from-crash/2546731#2546731

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a loop in which you essentially `fork()`, do the real work in the child, and just wait on the child and check its exit status in the parent.  You can also use a system which monitors and restarts programs in a similar fashion, such as daemontools, runit, etc.

Answer (score 11):

simplest is

```
while [ 1 ]; do ./program && break; done
```

basically, you run program until it is return 0, then you break.

Comment: This solution and [llasram's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703227/self-restart-program-on-segfault-under-linux/3703270#3703270) can make it difficult to kill the process intentionally (at a minimum the user most know what is going on...). This can be good or bad depending on the intended use.

Comment: @dmc of course, simplest is not necessarily good.  it's hard to say without knowing more about requirements. I like your answer because it is more robust.

Comment: Oh, I'm not complaining. This has the virtue of being bog-simple and sometime you *don't* want ignorant users killing it off...

Comment: @dmckee - [llasram's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703227/self-restart-program-on-segfault-under-linux/3703270#3703270) has the property that the parent can catch `SIGTERM`, signal the child, wait, and then exit in an orderly fashion. This answer should be adaptable to do the same -- bash's job control should be rich enough to support it.

Comment: @dmckee I added a `sleep 2` before restarting,so that a second Ctrl+C would stop the infinite loop.

Answer (score 7):

`SIGSEGV` can be caught (see `man 3 signal` or `man 2 sigaction`), and the program can call one of the `exec` family of function on itself in order to restart. Similarly for most runtime crashes (`SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, `SIGBUS`, `SIGSYS`, ...).

I'd think a bit before doing this, though. It is a rather unusual strategy for a unix program, and you may surprise your users (not necessarily in a pleasant way, either).

In any case, be sure to *not* auto-restart on `SIGTERM` if there are any resources you want to clean up before dying, otherwise angry users will use `SIGKILL` and you'll leave a mess.

Comment: Not a good idea, from the signal manpage: "According to POSIX, the behavior of a process  is  undefined  after  it ignores  a  SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV signal that was not generated by kill(2) or raise(3)."

Comment: @Paul: I hadn't noticed that before. The thing that is not clear to me is does running a handler that invokes exec on some static variable into which you have copied argv[0] constitute "ignoring" the signal. My instinct is to claim that it does not. In any case I have been able to reliably handle SIGSEGV on Mac OS and linux. I can't recall handling SIGFPE, and I don't think I have every generated SIGILL or SIGBUS. Certainly the other suggestions here are good and accomplish what the OPs desires, but I took the title literally.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to what was proposed here:

Another option is to do like it is done for getty daemon. Please see /etc/inittab and appropriate inittab(5) man page. It seems it is most system-wide mean ;-).

It could look like file fragment below. Obvious advantage this mean is pretty standard and it allows to control your daemon through run levels.

```
# Run gettys in standard runlevels
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty1
2:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty2
3:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty3
4:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty4
5:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty5
6:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty6
```

Comment: That is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Processes can't restart themselves, but you could use a utility like [`crontab(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) to schedule a script to check if the process is still alive at regular intervals.

Comment: Nothing prevents a program from calling `exec` on `argv[0]` (almost always its own executable)...

Comment: The "crash" is the OS sending the signal (with default behavior "terminate process"). The default behavior can be replaced with a user defined function...

Comment: What if memory is so corrupt that you get a second SEGV in the SEGV handler?  Essentially it's more reliable to operate from another process.

Comment: I agree with @dmckee, AFAIK calling exec is basically another process with the same PID.  its a rebirth, all memory is lost (not sure if there are any issues with shared memory and similar resources that need explicit cleanup) [as long as the memory into which you copied argv[0] is clean you should be good]

Comment: @dmckee How replace the default behaviour? Can it be done from inside the program? What I mean, is can a program catch itself crashing and then restart itself.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `man sigaction (2)` You can catch some signals that cause termination, but not others.

Answer (score 1):

The program itself obviously shouldn't check whether it is running or not running :)

Most enterprise solutions are actually just fancy ways of grepping the output from `ps()` for a given string, and performing an action in the event that certain criteria are satisfied - i.e. if your process is not found, then call the start script.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code if its specific to segfault. This can be modified as required.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <signal.h> 
#include <setjmp.h> 
#include <poll.h>

sigjmp_buf buf; 
void handler(int sig) { 
siglongjmp(buf, 1); 
} 
int main() { 
//signal(SIGINT, handler); 
//register all signals
struct sigaction new_action, old_action;
new_action.sa_handler = handler;
sigemptyset (&new_action.sa_mask);
new_action.sa_flags = 0;

sigaction (SIGSEGV, NULL, &old_action);
if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
sigaction (SIGSEGV, &new_action, NULL);

if (!sigsetjmp(buf, 1)){
printf("starting\n"); 
//code or function/method here
}
else{  
printf("restarting\n"); 
 //code or function/method here
}
while(1) {
poll(NULL,0,100); //ideally use usleep or nanosleep. for now using poll() as a timer
printf("processing...\n");
}
return 0; //or exit(SUCESS)
}
```